# Cut the letter $M$ to obtain $9$ single triangles by drawing $3$ straight lines

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Cut the letter $M$ to obtain $9$ single triangles by drawing $3$ straight lines. A single triangle is a triangle such that there is no other triangle inside it.

Comment: Google image search "m nine triangles" and you can see the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are looking for:

[image: 9 triangles]

Source - [Math Forum's M-Puzzle](http://mathforum.org/k12/k12puzzles/mpuzzle.html)

Comment: More precisely, the source of the image is [The Math Forum's "M Puzzle" entry](http://mathforum.org/k12/k12puzzles/mpuzzle.html).